# Can I use tornado web server on windows without pycurl installed?

Tags: python, windows, tornado, pycurl

I am looking on how to use Tornado on Windows. From my recent searches I saw that to use the full capabilities of Tornado, one needs to install pycurl which is not supported on windows since python 2.6.

Does anyone know which can be the impacts if Tornado is installed without pycurl and which functionality will be lost ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tornado` provides [a couple of asynchronous HTTP clients](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html), one of which is pure python, and another that uses `pycurl`. In recent versions of `tornado` (2.0+) the pure python version is the default, and `pycurl` is only necessary if you explicitly try to use the `CurlAsyncHTTPClient`.

(The `curl` client is supposed to be faster and more robust in the face of bad HTTP, but when I tried to use it I'd get segfaults once in a while, so ya... it's not a critical part of `tornado` by any means; depending on your app you might not even need an HTTP client, and if you do and the default client is not good enough for whatever reason, you can always use a separate HTTP client, e.g. [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) which is awesome and has [support for asynchronous requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests)).